# Saving date and time to PostgreSQL using Delphi

Tags: postgresql, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a column in my PostgreSQL database, which is in `timestamp without time zone` format. I would like to save the current date there using the following code:

```
  MyStoredProc.ParamByName('date').Value := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.zzz', Now);
```

The `date` value in my stored procedure is declared as `DateTime`, but setting it to `PgTimeStamp` does not help either. The first column is created in PostgreSQL, timestamps working correctly, but the second one, where I´m trying to save data from my code, is always showing zeros.

[image: zero]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MyStoredProc.ParamByName('date').Value := 'now()::timestamp with time zone';` (_untested on Delphi environment_)

Comment: I use code similar to yours to save a `TDateTime` in my PostgreSQL database. My string format is the same. My db field is `creationTime     TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()`

Comment: why don't you use `dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss = 05/06/49 01:02:03` [delphi formats](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FormatDateTime) ?

Comment: @Dmitry because postgresql expects year-month-day hour:min:sec.ms as format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass directly the datetime object as parameter int his way :

```
 MyStoredProc.ParamByName('date').Value := Now;
```

or :

```
 MyStoredProc.ParamByName('date').AsDateTime := Now;
```

Of course the parameter of the PostgreSQL function must be timezone type.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It does not return errors like `Invalid STRING format` , but the numbers are still saved as zeros.

Comment: It could be a bug of the framework then, I'm used to work with zeos lib and I don't have any issue passing datetime object,  I can confirm that all the time part is stored .